# CloudWatch Events scheduled from Lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-sdk-js

I've tried to setup scheduling with Amazon CloudWatch Events, which should invoke a Lambda function, from another Lambda
I used guide from [Sending Events to Amazon CloudWatch Events - AWS SDK for JavaScript](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/cloudwatch-examples-sending-events.html).

The problem is, that even after setting CloudWatch Events IAM role

```
{
                    Sid: 'CloudWatchEventsFullAccess',
                    Effect: 'Allow',
                    Action: ['*'],
                    Resource: '*',
},
```

and Lambda role to similar one, when I invoke main function

```
const cloudWatchEvents = new CloudWatchEvents()

        const ruleParams = {
            Name: projectId,
            ScheduleExpression: crontab,
            State: 'ENABLED',
            RoleArn: apiCloudWatchEventsIamRole,
        }

        const targetParams = {
            Rule: projectId,
            Targets: [
                {
                    Arn: apiLongTaskFunctionArn,
                    Id: 'lambdaCloudWatch',
                },
            ],
        }


        cloudWatchEvents.putRule(ruleParams, (err, rule) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
                return err
            }
            cloudWatchEvents.putTargets(targetParams, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err)
                    return (err)
                }
                const eventParams = {
                    Entries: [
                        {
                            DetailType: 'Scheduled Event',
                            Source: 'aws.events',
                            Resources: [rule.RuleArn],
                            Detail: '{}',
                        },
                    ],
                }
                cloudWatchEvents.putEvents(eventParams, (err, data) => {
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err)
                        return (err)
                    }
                    console.log(data)
                })
            })
        })
```

i get response from last console.log

```
{ FailedEntryCount: 1,
      Entries: 
       [ { ErrorCode: 'NotAuthorizedForSourceException',
           ErrorMessage: 'Not authorized for the source.' } ] }
```

I'm not sure where should I search for answer, as I haven't seen this case documented anywhere on web.

Comment: Has the trust relationship been setup for the role? i.e. "Statement": [
      {
         "Effect": "Allow",
         "Principal": {
            "Service": "events.amazonaws.com"
         },
         "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
      }

Comment: @tedsmitt yep, I set 
Statement: [
     {
      Effect: 'Allow',
      Principal: {
       Service: ['lambda.amazonaws.com'],
      },
      Action: ['sts:AssumeRole'],
     },
     {
      Effect: 'Allow',
      Principal: {
       Service: ['events.amazonaws.com'],
      },
      Action: ['sts:AssumeRole'],
     },
    ],
for both lambda execution role and cloudWatch events role

Comment: I think the issue here is that the `aws.*` prefix is reserved for AWS itself to use. So when you try to specify your source as `aws.events`, it tells you you're not authorized to use that source. Although, I can't seem to find any documentation on this besides the end of this [blog post](https://chaosgears.com/how-to-test-service-events-in-aws-organizations-aws-cloudtrail/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

okay, so adding to ruleParams

```
            EventPattern: JSON.stringify({
                source: ['sourceName'],
            }),
```

and setting Entries to

```
                    Entries: [
                        {
                            DetailType: 'Scheduled Event',
                            Source: 'sourceName',
                            Resources: [rule.RuleArn],
                            Detail: '{}',
                        },
                    ],
```

solved the issue

Comment: Hi, this just listens to every cloudwatch event. I want to run a cron and pass cloudwatch event along with payload to the lambda